# jQuery + JSON how to define key from variable

Tags: jquery, string, json, variables

I have the following code

```
$.post(
    "/factory/set",{
         key : value
    },
    function(response) {

        });
    }, "json"
);
```

where

```
key = "foo"
value = "bar"
```

but the server always gets "key" and "bar", is there a way to set the key as variable, not string?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Create an object:

```
var data = {};
```

Then set the property:

```
data[key] = value;
```

Then use the object in your call to `$.post()`:

```
$.post(
    "/factory/set",data,
    function(response) {

    }, "json"
);
```