# using variable on left side of json syntax

Tags: javascript, json, github, github-api, gist

I'm creating a github-gist using javascript/ajax.

i want to provide my own file name. Below is the data which is in json.

```
var data = {
  "description": gist_description,
  "public": true,
  "files": {
    "file.txt" : {
       "content": gist_content
     }
  }
};
```

i wrote var gist_filename = "main.txt";

I replaced "file.txt" with my variable name i.e gist_filename: { "content" : ......};
But actually the gist is created with the name `gist_filename` instead of the actual name in the variable i.e `main.txt`

Though assignment on right hand side,for eg, "content" : gist_content is giving me the right content stored in the variable named gist_content.

Any possible suggestions. Don't know much json.
Thanks!

Comment: You cannot do that. It would *not* be JSON. The `var data = {..` bit is JavaScript (JSON is a subset of JavaScript object literal syntax). Anyway, I what I am saying: this question makes little sense as written. More context may help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery + JSON how to define key from variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055919/jquery-json-how-to-define-key-from-variable)

Comment: instead of "file.txt" i just want my variable to work there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10055993/1773904), you need to first create the object, and then assign a key with a variable by using the `my_obj[x] = y` syntax.

Your situation

```
var gist_description = "desc...",
    gist_content = "content...";
var data = {
  "description": gist_description,
  "public": true,
  "files": {
  }
}
var filename = "myfile.txt";
data["files"][filename] = {
    "content": gist_content
}
```

Comment: i tried as `var gname = {}; gname[gist_filename]=gist_filename ' and then put `gname: {"contents":gist_content}`. It didn't work

Comment: Hah, anytime :) - please could you select it as the right answer?